# Nuget Package cannot be installed in NET Core v1.1 Project

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, .net-core

Trying to build a project with a reference to a package that should be compatible with .net core 1.1 but when nuget is restoring packages (VS.NET 2017 or the command line) I an see an error message

"One or more of the packages are incompatible with netcoreapp1.1"

The package name is

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AzureStorage
```

It says it is compatible with .NET Standard v1.5

And the error relates to dependencies of the package:

```
Microsoft.Data.Edm
Microsoft.Data.Services.Client
Microsoft.Data.OData
Microsoft.Data.Spatial
```

The csproj file has a package fallback setting:

```
<PackageTargetFallback>
    $(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;
</PackageTargetFallback>
```

Not sure what the problem is

thanks
Michael

Comment: What is your project targeting? .NET Standard or .NET Core? Which version? Which version of the package are you using?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this.

Comment: Also just created a netstandard1.5 and netcoreapp1.1 library and adding this package works with the provided `PackageTargetFallback`. @Mlantosca can you share the output of `dotnet restore`?

Comment: problem solved - added the PackageTargetFallback setting to the Unit Test project - it was already added to the other 2 projects in the solution. The error list and build log did not specify which project the error was happening in. Thanks